# Printing an inverted triangle with a * at the bottom in C Code

Tags: c

sorry i need help once again. I've been given a homework which requires to print this on screen. However, there are various requirements i have to meet. To be honest im really stuck because when i check online, i have to consider the spaces and it doesnt show me how to edit the little tip at the bottom of the triangle into another. This is what i've done but considering the number of cases i have to do, its really crazy and i dont think its doable. Please help! Thank you so much in advance.

1) The top base length has to be a user input with a maximum number of up till 79 (Base Length=79).

2) The triangle has to be symmetric.

```
xxxxxxxxx
 xxxxxxx
  xxxxx
   xxx
    *

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i, space, base_length, star;
printf("Enter the base length:\n");
scanf("%d",&base_length);

if (base_length==15)
{
    printf("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n");
    printf(" XXXXXXXXXXXXX\n");
    printf("  XXXXXXXXXXX\n");
    printf("   XXXXXXXXX\n");
    printf("    XXXXXXX\n");
    printf("     XXXXX\n");
    printf("      XXX\n");
    printf("       *\n");
}
else if (base_length==13)
{
    printf(" XXXXXXXXXXXXX\n");
    printf("  XXXXXXXXXXX\n");
    printf("   XXXXXXXXX\n");
    printf("    XXXXXXX\n");
    printf("     XXXXX\n");
    printf("      XXX\n");
    printf("       *\n");
}
else if (base_length==11)
{
    printf("  XXXXXXXXXXX\n");
    printf("   XXXXXXXXX\n");
    printf("    XXXXXXX\n");
    printf("     XXXXX\n");
    printf("      XXX\n");
    printf("       *\n");
}

else if (base_length==9)
{
    printf("   XXXXXXXXX\n");
    printf("    XXXXXXX\n");
    printf("     XXXXX\n");
    printf("      XXX\n");
    printf("       *\n");
}

else if (base_length==7)
{
    printf("    XXXXXXX\n");
    printf("     XXXXX\n");
    printf("      XXX\n");
    printf("       *\n");
}

else if (base_length==5)
{
    printf("     XXXXX\n");
    printf("      XXX\n");
    printf("       *\n");
}

else if (base_length==3)
{
    printf("      XXX\n");
    printf("       *\n");
}

else if  (base_length==1)
{
    printf("       *\n");
}
else
{
    printf("The maximum base length permitted is 79 and has to be an odd number.\nPlease try again with a valid number.\nThank You!!!");
}

return;
```

}

Comment: you have to derive a formula for each line you have to print, depending on the user info, then you need to use a loop for the lines and apply this formula

Comment: The first line should be easy: just print as many `X` as the number the user entered. Now try to derive one for the 2nd, 3rd, ..nth line

Comment: Use a char buffer and set the characters in there instead of printing them directly. That will likely be more instructive to you and much cleaner code to read. (Bonus points if you can do the line formatting without loops or recursion.)

Comment: `return;` : Must return a value.

Comment: For each  line, there's `x` X's and `s` spaces. The user enters the value of X's for the first line so `s` must zero. Each line after that has two fewer X's and two more spaces.  Half the spaces are on the left of the X's and the other half that would be on the right, can be ignored.

Comment: [This question has been asked and answered many times.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D%2Binverted%2Btriangle)

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the pattern and replace it with iteration.

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i, base_length, space, x;
    int bias_space = 7, rows;
    const char *X79 = //Prepare in advance because the maximum length is fixed
        "XXXXXXXXXX"
        "XXXXXXXXXX"
        "XXXXXXXXXX"
        "XXXXXXXXXX"
        "XXXXXXXXXX"
        "XXXXXXXXXX"
        "XXXXXXXXXX"
        "XXXXXXXXX";

    printf("Enter the base length:\n");
    scanf("%d", &base_length);

    if(base_length < 1 || base_length > 79 || (base_length & 1) == 0){
        printf("The maximum base length permitted is 79 and has to be an odd number.\nPlease try again with a valid number.\nThank You!!!");
        return -1;
    }
    rows = base_length / 2;//Number of rows excluding the top
    bias_space -= rows;
    if(bias_space < 0) //When there are more than 7 lines, there is no bias space.
        bias_space = 0;

    for(i = rows, space = 0, x = base_length; i--; space++, x -= 2)
        printf("%*s%.*s\n", bias_space + space, "", x, X79);
    printf("%*s%c\n", bias_space + space, "", '*');
}
```

Comment: Almost correct. An overly complicated solution to a very simple problem and you shouldn't be supplying full solutions for a student question.

Comment: I am not overly complicated. Rather it is a simple solution. Of course, I can show a partial solution, but I try to present things that are feasible as much as possible in such cases. I am tired of being told that "It does not work".

Comment: We can help the OP complete their homework, without us writing the code for them. It's one thing to show off your skills to a peer-class programmer and entirely something different helping a student to cheat on their homework assignments.

Comment: I do not need your idea.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a simple recursive function with a help function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void triangle(int size);
void triangle_aux(int size, int n);

int main()
{
    int base_length;

    printf("Enter the base length:\n");
    scanf("%d",&base_length);

    if(base_length < 1 || base_length > 79 || base_length%2 == 0)
        printf("The maximum base length permitted is 79 and has to be an odd number.\nPlease try again with a valid number.\nThank You!!!");
    else
        triangle(base_length);
}

void triangle(int size) {
    triangle_aux(size, 0);
}

void triangle_aux(int size, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf(" ");
    if(n==size/2)
        printf("*\n");
    else {
         for(i=n; i<size-n; i++)
              printf("X");
         printf("\n");
         triangle_aux(size, n+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code for their homework assignments.  Teach them how to think algorithmically instead.

Comment: @jwdonahue Don't know if you were the one who downvoted, but I do not see this as a good reason to downvote a correct answer. Discussion about it here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions

Comment: I didn't DV your post.  Though I probably will if you don't actually delete it and I have reason to return to this question.

Comment: Hi sorry for the inconvenienced caused! Thank you so much for the correct code though. At the end of the day, it will be on me if i do not learn the proper steps for it.